# All combination for a number using + and - C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I want to make a recursive method to find all the possible combination for a number using +/-, with a specific length for example:
For input:

- length : 6
- Number : 3

And for the output:

- 1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 5 + 6 = 3
- 1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 = 3
- 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 = 3

Can you explain for me how can I do that ?
Thanks you.

Comment: There can be infinite cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, assuming that "all combinations" must be generated from **consequent natural numbers** starting from **1** (`1, 2, 3, ..., n`) you can implement something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Here we generate all possible formulae and their sums:
// 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6
// 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 + 6
// 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 + 5 - 6
// 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 
// ...
// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6
private static IEnumerable<(string formula, int sum)> GenerateRecursive(int number) {
  if (number == 1) 
    yield return ("1", 1);
  else
    foreach (var pair in GenerateRecursive(number - 1)) {
      yield return ($"{pair.formula} - {number}", pair.sum - number);
      yield return ($"{pair.formula} + {number}", pair.sum + number);
    }
}

// Here we query formulae generated for having required sum
private static IEnumerable<string> SolveFor(int target, int count) {
  return GenerateRecursive(count)
    .Where(item => item.sum == target)
    .Select(item => $"{item.formula} = {item.sum}");
}
```

And then

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, SolveFor(3, 6)));
```

**Outcome:**

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 = 3
1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 = 3
1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 5 + 6 = 3
```